# MySQL: What happens to the row when skip-errors=1062 is set

Tags: mysql, replication

I found out that I can set `skip-errors=1062` in the `my.cnf` but I need to know what happens to the row when the error happens. Does it get silently dropped? Or is that config option the equivalent to `STOP SLAVE;SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1; START SLAVE;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is equivalent, provided the slave error you are skipping is 1062 (Duplicate Key)

It would have to appear in the `[mysqld]` section of my.cnf like this

```
[mysqld]
slave-skip-errors=1062
```

All other error numbers will stop the SQL thread and would require

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;
START SLAVE;
```

to have replication conitnue

If you have multiple error numbers to skip, it should be a comma-delimited list of error numbers

```
[mysqld]
slave-skip-errors=1062,1053
```

For more information, please read the [**MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_slave-skip-errors) on it.

You asked

> Does it get silently dropped?

Yes it does. Just remember that any non-key columns that were supposed to change will not change.

Comment: is this a good solution having two slaves and a lot of  `auto increment` tables? I'm getting this error a lot of times and I'm sick of them.